# (R) Did I successfully make a linear model to see if these categorical variables have an effect on a numerical variable?

Tags: r, linear-model

I have to make a linear model to see if two categorical variables: "USA_origin" and "gender" will affect the numerical variable "toy_age".

What I did was:

```
lm69 = lm(toy_age ~ USA_origin + gender, data = toydaddy)
summary(lm69)
```

and the results were:

```
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -5.1520 -1.1520  0.0000  0.9768  3.8480 
## 
## Coefficients:
##                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)       6.6030     1.8249   3.618 0.000494 ***
## genderMale        1.3970     0.5864   2.382 0.019361 *  
## genderFemale      2.2681     0.6970   3.254 0.001614 ** 
## USA_originTRUE   -1.7581     1.7504  -1.004 0.317961    
## USA_originFAL    -0.8480     1.7504  -0.484 0.629276    
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 1.728 on 88 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.1703, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1326 
## F-statistic: 4.516 on 4 and 88 DF,  p-value: 0.002299
```

Am I now right to conclude that gender will affect toy_age but USA_origin will not? Or should I run two separate lm()s to see their individual results?

Answer (score 1):

As your dependent variables are categorical, you can perform ANOVA. I didn't using a random sample.

```
USA_origin <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 40, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(c('MALE', 'FEMALE'), 40, replace = TRUE)
toy_age <- runif(40, min = 5, max = 36)
toydaddy<- as.data.frame(cbind(USA_origin, gender, toy_age))
toydaddy$toy_age<- as.numeric(toydaddy$toy_age)

mod1 <- aov(toy_age ~ USA_origin*gender, data = toydaddy)
summary(mod1)
```

The output is

```
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
USA_origin         1    292   291.6   2.511  0.122  
gender             1    325   324.9   2.798  0.103  
USA_origin:gender  1    533   532.9   4.589  0.039 *
Residuals         36   4181   116.1                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

By performing ANOVA, you can also check the interaction effect and plot the interaction.